# Facebook: wall post 'picture' element is ignored

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook C# SDK in order to post on my business facebook page. For a product that I have on the site I want to do a post on the wall that have picture and description.

I have the following code for this:

```
  var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  args["message"] = "Product description ... ";
  args["caption"] = "Last offer !!!";
  args["description"] = "Product description ... ";
  args["name"] = "Product name ... "
  //picture field is the link to my image on my site
  args["picture"] = "http://mydomain.com" + Url.Action("ImageFile", "Files", new {sizes = "400x650", fileName = file.FileName}); 
  args["link"] = Url.Abs(Url.Action("Details", "Product", new {id = id}));
```

All fields are ok except the image. The image is completely ignored and not displayed in the wall post.

My target is to have the same behavior as in the case when I manually paste the product details in 'My status' field and it is generated such a message containing first image and first paragraph.

PS: Can this be related with some facebook application security settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of debugging I found the problem. First thing to notice is that I am using MVC 3. The problem was with my link format. The next code works:

```
 var pictureLink = "http://mydomain.com" + Url.Action("ImageFile", "Files", new {sizes = "400x650", fileName = file.FileName});
 pictureLink = Server.UrlDecode(pictureLink);
 args["picture"] = pictureLink;
```

In my case the link was containing some characters that were encoded. You have to send the link as it is to facebook and they will encode it in url format.

Comment: fb c# sdk should auto decode that for you. which version of sdk are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting, remove the args["link"] and see if it posts the image.  If not, then there's something wrong with the permissions on the picture url that facebook is trying to access.  If it does post the picture without the link argument, then change the link argument to an "action" argument "name" and "link" to see if you can get your link included with the posting.